# Changing visreg line colour

Tags: r, plot, regression, lm, visreg

I'm using the R package visreg to visualise the results of a model. I want to change the colour of the regression line from the default blue to black. Adding `col = "black"` doesn't help. How do I make this change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `col = black` in the `line.par` argument:

```
fit <- lm(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp,data=airquality)
visreg(fit, line.par = list(col = 'black'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This was really bugging me, I kept overlooking that line.par has to be a list.